# Why this c++ program is not producing a runtime error

Tags: c++, class

Why the below program is not producing a runtime error!!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class temp
{
    public:
       void func(){cout<<"it works"<<endl;}
};

 int main()
{
   temp* ptr = NULL;
   ptr->func();
   return 0;
}
```

this code prints "it works" why?? ptr is accessing NULL memory it should crash.

if the explanation is that class has no member variables , then i tried the following code and it also works why??

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class temp
{
   int i;
    public:
       void func(){cout<<"it works"<<endl;}
};

 int main()
{
   temp* ptr = NULL;
   ptr->func();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try printing `i` in your member function.

Comment: there is no access of anything via ptr. Try to use `i` in your second example `func()`

Comment: void func(){cout<<"it works"<<endl;} makes no use of `this`, so it never realizes  `this` is NULL.

Comment: It's not a virtual function and you never dereference `this`. I wouldn't be surprised if this was undefined behavior though (ie, don't rely on it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Undefined behavior.

A C++ program is allowed to do pretty much anything it wants when the standard says the behavior is undefined. And one **must** understand that undefined behavior includes "pretend that everything is working fine".

---

What probably happens here is that the compiler recognizes that, in any situation where behavior is well-defined, calling `func()` will result in printing "it works". Since it's allowed to do anything it wants when behavior is ill-defined, it does the simplest thing (which is also the most efficient in the defined cases) and *always* results in printing "it works" regardless of whether or not it's being invoked on a valid object.

Answer (score 1):

`class temp` is trivial and has no special hidden information like a vtable that needs `this` to screw things up on `func`'s method call and `void func(){cout<<"it works"<<endl;}` makes no use of `this`, so it never realizes `this` is NULL and accesses outside bounds.

It should be noted that even if `this` was used, there is no certainty of a crash. The program could declare undefined behaviour and brutally murder a unicorn instead.